# How to set shapedrawable's border and fill colours to different colours

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to set the border colour and fill colour of a shapedrawable to different colours. How can I set both colours and have the shape as fill and stroke?

Say I have this:

```
        ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());

        border.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        border.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
        border.getPaint().setStrokeColour(Color.BLACK); //???????? How to do
```

Edit: My question is not a duplicate of [Android ShapeDrawable set Background and Border programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103974/android-shapedrawable-set-background-and-border-programmatically) because that question's only answer is unclear and does not help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ShapeDrawable set Background and Border programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103974/android-shapedrawable-set-background-and-border-programmatically)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/8089770

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define your drawable in XML instead. It would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/WHITE"/>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/BLACK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you might define an xml like below and use it where you need:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:radius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c9d1d7"/>
</shape>
```